# React Native - HERE maps unauthorized error

Tags: react-native, heremaps

I have a react native application that uses `react-native-maps` and HERE map api.

Here's my `useEffect`

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchDirections = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get(
              `https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?
{API_KEY}&waypoint0=geo!${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}&waypoint1=geo!${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&legAttributes=shape`,
            );
            if (response.data.status === 'OK') {
              setDirections(response.data);
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
            return error;
          }
        };
```

My `API_KEY_CODE` is generated from HERE website, the problem is whenever the `useEffect` is triggered it gives me this error

```
data: {
  error: "Forbidden"
  error_description: "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
```

Comment: Please, provide error codes in text format (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)